# Calculation Of Resulting 2D Image After Lens

Tags: optics, lenses, image-processing

This is a tough question!
I would like to calculate how an image (a real 2D photograph) looks if I place a lens at a certain distance d1 from it and I observe it at a certain distance $d_2$.

It is frustrating. All textbook always only treat 1D Images.

***Geometric distorsion:***

1. Image (2D photograph)

[image]

2. I place a lens at a certain distance d1 above my image and look at the lens  at a certain distance $d_2$. This is what I would get:

[image]

I have looked into Ray transfer matrix analysis, but I could't figure out how to compute such a distorsion of the image, which is also coherent with physics.

***Image blurr***

Another effect of a lens, is that things can appear in focus or out of focus depending on the focal distance $f$ and your position $d_2$.

1. Image in focus $d2=f$

[image]

2. Image out of focus $d2 < f$ or $d2 > f$

[image]

In the end I would like to write a neat mathematica code, in which you can import an image and based on the parameters, $d1$, $f$ and $d2$ it will create the resulting image, including distorsion and blurr in a physical meaningfull way.

But first I need to understand the physics correctly. :)

I would highly appreciate any help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, one needs to understand that there may be additional lenses, such as the one in your eye or in the camera that help to produce the image that your see. If we ignore such a lens and consider only one lens then one can compute the result as follows. (One can include the additional lenses, but then computation would need a few extra steps.)

Let's assume there is an object at $z=0$, scattering light toward an observer (in the $z$-direction). Between the object and the observer ther is a lens located at $z=L_1$ and the observer is located at $z=L_2>L_1$.

The light shown in your images is poly-chromatic (consist of multiple colours). So you'll need to perform the calculation for all the different colours and then add the results.

The first step is the perform the free space propagation of the light coming from the object. The general expression takes the form
$$ g(u,v) = \int f(x,y) K_z(u-x,v-y) dx dy . $$
Here $f(x,y)$ is the two-dimensional function of the light field coming from the object, in the plane of the object; $g(u,v)$ is the light field at a location $z$; and $K_z(u-x,v-y)$ is the appropriate kernel function for propagation of the light over a distance $z$. The nature of the kernel function depends on the nature of the light, namely, whether it is coherent, or incoherent. In case the light is coherent, the kernel is given by the Fresnel kernel
$$ K_z(u-x,v-y) = \Phi(u-x,v-y) , $$
where
$$ \Phi(x,y) = \frac{i}{\lambda z} \exp\left[\frac{-i\pi}{\lambda z}(x^2+y^2)\right] . $$
(Here, I've used the convention that phase increases with time.) The kernel function in the case of incoherent imagining is a bit more complicated. In general one needs to consider the propagation of the mutual coherence function of the optical field, which is the correlation function of the optical field with itself, each of which is propagated as if it is a coherent field. See for instance the [van Cittert-Zernike theorem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Cittert%E2%80%93Zernike_theorem)

So the idea is now to propagate the light all the way to the lens. Then one multiplies the light field with the transmission function of the lens, which is given by
$$ t(x,y) = \exp\left[\frac{i\pi}{\lambda f}(x^2+y^2)\right] , $$
where $f$ is the focal length of the lens.
The result after the lens is then propagated again over the distance between the lens and the observer. Again, the situation is a bit more involved with incoherent light. I suggest you read up on [optical transfer functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_transfer_function) for a general treatment.

You'll notice that the expressions depend on the wavelength $\lambda$. So if the image contains multiple colours one needs to perform this computation for all the different wavelengths (colours) and then add (or integrate over) the results in the end.

Hope this addresses your needs.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I would like to clarify and ask some
things. I am refering to the book,~Laser Beam Propagation: Generation
and Propagation of Customized Light: http://goo.gl/p0K83H

Comment: 1. Propagation through air: 

Indeed the propagation process can be expressed as a convolution integral
$g(x,y)=\int\int g(x,y)K_{z}(u,v;x,y)dxdy$, but the propagation kernel,
as in equation 1.98 looks different to me than in the book. Why is
that ?

Comment: 2. In the Paraxial Approximation of the lens (Fresnel), the propagation
kernel also ads a $e^{-ikz}$ ( I think that k is the wavenumber).
Why don't you add it ?

Comment: 3. You say that in the end one has to multiply the light field with
the transmission function of the lens... When I read p.33 of
the book, I feel like one has to recompute the integral, with
the transmission function of the lens being the new kernel, see eq.
1.118

Comment: could you help me to clarify those 3 questions ? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Wow, I wrote the first chapter of that book.

Comment: 1. OK I've modified the expression so that it is a convolution integral now. Before I gave a more general expression, which was not a convolution integral, but since the process is shift invariant is can be expressed as a convolution integral. Now it would agree with Eq (1.97).

Comment: 2. The factor $exp(-ikz)$ is a global phase factor that one can drop, because it does not effect anything that is observable.

Comment: 3. Actually, if you read carefully, you'll see that the transmission function of the lens in multiplied with the result after the first free-space propagation. But then this all sits inside the integral for the subsequent free-space propagation. So it looks like a kernel. Actually it isn't.

Comment: Oh, wow ! You wrote the first chapter ? Very nice! I like it a lot! Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Question 3: I still don't quite understand, what exactly you mean with "one multiplies the light field with the transmission function", from your chapter, it seems to me that you would actually do this: $h(a,b)=\int g(u,v)\psi(a-u,b-v)dudv$ with $\psi(x,y)=t(x,y)$ and  $h(a,b)$
 would be your resulting image behind the lens. Is that correct ? I might have missed something, and I am sorry if I am bothering you, but this part is still not clear to me.

Comment: No, at least not in position space. A transmission function operates on the field that is incident on it by multiplying each point of the field with the transmission at that point. If you transform to the Fourier domain then multiplication is converted into a convolution. So your expression would be correct in the Fourier domain where the fields are functions of spatial frequencies.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I think, that I understand it now. ... and If I want to simulate a setup with two lenses on the optical axis, I would just redo the calculation, this time taking the light field  behind the first lens as $f(x,y)$ , right ?

Comment: Yes, that's right